# Error with library paths while running Qt app from IDE

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am using *Qt5* on *MacOS* and have created a small app that connects to an oracle database. I successfully compiled and built the drivers and placed them inside the *sqldrivers* directory. In order to work the driver needs

```
/ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
```

as reported by **otool -L**

That directory does not exist so I had to create it and add the library myself as well as change the permissions. This library on its turn if we look the otool output

```
/ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/ade/dosulliv_ldapmac/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

needs

```
/ade/dosulliv_ldapmac/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib
```

So I again took this library from the **64 bit** **instantclient** provided by oracle and copied it at the required directory.

Trying to run the app from inside Qt though I get the error

```
QOCIDriver: unable to create environment
```

and the program crashes.

If again I just go inside **myTest.app/Contents/MacOS** and run the executable from terminal it connects to the database. How is this possible?